# what is the relationship between worst case execution time (WCET) and cpu utilization of a raspberry pi zero

Tags: pi-zero, cpu, measuring

Assuming the task execution in case of single core processor be sequential, how can we possible relate the WCET of any program to CPU utilization of task and/or core frequency at which the task is being executed?

From 'Perf' command in Linux, I obtained following values for a piece of code (application):

1. Core frequency at which the code was run
2. time elapsed (msec) for whole code to execute
3. L1 dcache loads, %age of L1 dcache loads, and L1 dcache loads in M/sec
4. L1 dcache load miss, %age of L1 dcache load misses amongst all hits
5. L1 dcache store miss, %age L1 dcache store miss, and L1 dcache store misses in M/sec
6. L1 dcache stores, %age of L1 dcache stores, L1 dcache stores in M/sec
7. L1 icache load misses, %age of L1 icache load misses
8. no. of cycles required to execute the code, %age of cycles required at a particular core frequency (GHz)
9. Total  no. of instructions, %age of total no. of instructions, IPC
10. CPU clock (ms), part of CPU utilised
11. branches, % branches
12. dTLB load misses, % dTLB load misses
13. dTLB store misses, % dTLB store misses
14. iTLB load misses, % iTLB load misses
15. stalled cycles front end, stalled cycles backend

Comment: No way of doing that, unless the OS has some sort of guarantees regarding scheduling, like QNX does. On Linux, a program can be stuck indefinitely for no reason.

Comment: I have edited the question with the details that I have in this. Now if you could help me?